# sharepoint workflow dll not being found

Tags: sharepoint

I have a very simple workflow that is just trying to send an email with the task title, but I can't get it to run.  I always get a "failed to start" error.  The logs report back that "Load Workflow Assembly: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" for my dll.  I did load it into the gac using the gacutil.exe command with a new strong name key.  I'm guessing it's just something simple that I'm missing, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "new strong name key", could it be that you are refering to the dll with the old key?

**EDIT**

As colin says below, check the sharepoint web.config for reference to the strong name key.

Comment: Hmm, not sure...  I went into the project properties and created a new strong name key file, then rebuilt the project and deployed it.  Is there something else that I have to do after I create the new key?

Comment: Ok, so I did go and look in the assembly folder, and the public key token listed is different then what is reported in the error log...

Comment: Not sure which is old and which is new. Easiest way to fix it would be to uninsatll everything, then recompile everything, and the reinstall. Then you are suer that the versions match

Comment: Use the key stated in the GAC, that is the current (new) one. Have SharePoint reference that dll in the web.config etc.